# Regexp for header_checks in postfix

Tags: postfix, regex, pcre

All my users use outlook, so the From field reaches the postfix like this:
From: "Name and Surname" address@something.com.
I need a regular expression to change the address, I have this in the file header_checks:

```
/^(From: "(?:[^"]|"")*" <reservas1@domain.co.cu>)$/ REPLACE From: "Reservas" <reservas@domain.co.cu>
```

and in the file main.cf have:

```
...
header_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/header_checks
...
```

Conclusion, what I need iswhen the reservas1 and reservas2 email addresses send an email change the address for reservas@domain.co.cu.

Thanks to anyone!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called *Address Rewriting* which is detailed in this postfix official page: [here](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html).

More precisely *sender_canonical_maps* since you are rewriting sender addresses.

1/ Create a file that contains the real sender address and the desired rewritten address, like so:

```
$ cat /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
reservas1@domain.co.cu reservas@domain.co.cu
reservas2@domain.co.cu reservas@domain.co.cu
```

2/ Point the *sender_canonical_maps* parameter to this this file in
your main.cf:

```
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
```

3/ postmap the file and reload postfix

```
$ sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sender_canonical
$ sudo postfix reload
```